# why my setup in mysql in vs code is not working?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code, mysql-workbench, root, setup-deployment

So basically, I'm following this tutorial.
[LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnW1forz4Sw).

wherein I setup the MySQL Localhost first in the Vscode after that I will to the cmd part
and do this `mysql -u root -p`

After that I have to input my password in my MySQL...but I don't know if the password is already created or should I have created it in the tutorial. I just type the password in Vscode process "mathlearnerxx" but it doesn't work. Does the MySQL password is what you already done before install in the MySQL before?? I don't remember my password when I follow a tutorial about setup the MySQL.

Anyways after the error of password I input "mathlearnerxx". It gives me something like this

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: *************
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

which I basically followed in tutorial.

Can anyone help me with this? I have some project to done thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: Nope this wasn't. It is 10yrs ago and not working anymore.

Comment: I'm looking for how password works. Do I have to create new localhost or root or whatsoever? just to make it work?